# How to maintain completely dynamic convex hull quickly?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, computational-geometry

If there's no deletion, we can use $2$ balanced trees to maintain $2$ half convex hulls(up and down). In this way, we can insert $n$ points in $O(n\log n)$ time.(In the beginning, there are no points)

A completely dynamic convex hull means that I can insert and delete a point without rebuilding the whole convex hull, which costs $O(n)$'s time.

My problem is, is there any solutions to deleting points quickly? Maybe it could be solved with persistent data structures, but up to now, I haven't come up with any concrete method yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was first solved by Jacob and Brodal in 2002; there is a recent arXiv submission of that work, ["Dynamic Planar Convex Hull"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.11169).

Answer (score 2):

You can use my code. I implemented the ideas from the paper by Overmars and van Leeuwen.
https://github.com/sumeetshirgure/DynamicPlanarHull/tree/master